# Align CSS Button in Center and add Rounded Corners

Tags: html, css

I've tried using `position:center` and `middle` in the CSS. In the HTML code I've tried `align="center;middle"` but nothing seems to work. I need the button to be aligned in the center of the page and not to the left. I've replaced several codes but still nothing. The corners won't change either.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LnSRb/)

Here's the HTML code:

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul>
  <li class='has-sub last' id="iefix">
    <a rel=nofollow href='#'><span>Choose a model</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li id="iefix"><a rel=nofollow href='#'><span>iPhone 3GS</span></a></li>
      <li id="iefix"><a rel=nofollow href='#'><span>iPhone 4</span></a></li>
      <li id="iefix"><a rel=nofollow href='#'><span>iPhone 4S</span></a></li>
      <li class='last'  id="iefix"><a rel=nofollow href='#'><span>iPhone 5</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: HTML notes: ids are unique identifiers. You can't reuse them for multiple elements, so you want to use classes here. Also, don't use `<a>` if it's not a hyperlink. The `href='#'` concept is from a version of HTML people don't even remember anymore. Use a <span> for text-span wrapping. If you need the "it's a clickable thing!" use the css `cursor: pointer` rule so that people will think it's a navigation link (`href='#'` means "navigate to the root of this page")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 29 you set the `float` of the button to `left`. Change this to `text-align:center;`, and the button will be centered

```
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  text-align:center;
}
```

Then, if you target the `a`, you should be able to get the border radius to change.

```
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  border-radius:10px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LnSRb/8/)

Comment: The list under the ul seems to expand out of control

Answer (score 1):

`text-align:center` for the container div and `display:inline-block` for the ul do the trick - http://jsfiddle.net/LnSRb/3/

Answer (score 0):

**Version 1:**

```
#cssmenu ul {
  width: 165px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LnSRb/1/)

**Version 2:**

```
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LnSRb/7/)

Answer (score 0):

try setting a fixed width on the "cssmenu" element, and then add margin: 0 auto, like this:

```
#cssmenu {
    width: 205px;   
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Then, remove the padding from the ul menu by doing this:

```
#cssmenu ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

To make the button in center of the screen

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <button class="button">Hello</button>
</div>

.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}

.button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
```

Try the below link to check the rounded corners:-

[Rounded Corners](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/article.php/3891201)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make these changes.

```
<div id='cssmenu' style="width:980px; margin:auto;">
  <ul style="width:170px; margin:auto">
```